# How are blockchain HD address queried

Tags: blockchain, hierarchical, deterministic

Hardware wallets can generate Hierarchical Deterministic addresses.

I guess these addresses (and their pub/priv keypairs) are in some way derived by multiple hashing the root public key (derived from the ultimate seed)

I can email such a "use once" invoice address to someone to receive cryptomoney.
The amount of received cryptomoney is then in the blockchain as an unspent block in some way connected to this address.

If later i want to query the blockchain for my total account or want to make a payment.
How is this block then found again?
My hardware cryptodevice (ledger nano s) does not keep track of all generated addresses.

Can someone explain this in terms of the basic cryptgraphic functions (ecc pub/priv keys, signing, hashing, assymetric/symmetric encrytion,...).

What info is (my root public key?) supplied to the blockchain server to find all address i ever
used?

Answer (score 1):

im Toni, and I'm Blockchain Develop hard wallet have own BTC or another crypto private key with a private key u can accses wallet with pc app and make tx or something pub key is your address. Hashing every tx is hashed with miracle tree its something like this 1st tx = hash 123 2nd tx hash = 456 3rd = 789 with miracle tree all that hashes combie in one block hash what will be 123456789, also I want to explain how BTC tx work imagine it like this I send you one box locked with a key when u get it u put another lock on it then u send it back to me and I unlock my key but it's still locked then I send it back to you and it's locked with your key and none could get data from the chest. and not replace your 'gold' in chest with something different